# Is there a way to pass data from one view to modalviewcontroller

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiview, presentmodalviewcontroller

I have a view with a UIView and a button. Pressing the button brings up a ModalViewController which is UIView with UITextField in it. I need to pass the string value of NSObject in the UIView to the ModalViewController as a string. On button click I call this:

```
-(void) editNote{

TextViewController * vc = [(TextViewController *)[TextViewController alloc] init];
UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:vc];

[self.navigationController presentModalViewController:nav animated:YES];
[vc release];
}
```

Normally, on row select we push the data using pushviewcontroller to the next view but after doing lot of google I cannot figure out how to pass the data using presentmodalviewcontroller.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could add a property to TextViewController, then just use `vc.object = myObject`. Or you could make a new `init` method that takes some more information.

Comment: Property's the way to go. If you have more pressing needs (table view, for example), you could set up a delegate system with the main controller as the delegate.

Comment: The choice between whether to use a property or passing in a var in an `init` method should be distinguished a bit better. If it is essential that the object needs the information to be considered fully formed then you should enforce that the init method requires it. If it is not essential then a property is fine and you may additionally consider making an init method that can accept the var as a convenience.